# Hello, I am a science graduate, looking to learn about economics, any suggestions where can i start?

Tags: reference-request

Any books you can suggest might be amazing, i am completely new to this and it would be a huge help if you guys could help me out

Comment: I don't think it is possible to answer your question without learning more about your intentions. Are you learning "economics" as a hobby? Or do you need to be familiar with a subfield for your job? Do you want to switch to academic economics (which branch)?

Comment: i intend to learn economics as a hobby, but i want to learn deeply and i am aware it is a vast subject to cover, but if i get an idea where i can start, i think i would get to know more about where my interest lies. Muflon suggested a good book, i think i will start with that. Thankyou for your comment

Answer (score 1):

If you want birds eye overview of economics as a field, written in very objective and balanced manner then you want:

The Economics Book: Big Ideas Simply Explained from DK publishing.

DK publishing made a series of books (Big Ideas Simply Explained) for all fields (physics, chemistry, political science, sociology etc) they are all excellent books to learn about different field.

However, they are written from a perspective of someone who is complete laymen in the field so they are very basic. You won't learn any complex model in them or get rigorous explanations for various economic phenomena.

If you want to start learning economics more seriously than just for having some basic overview you should definitely pick some standard textbook.

If you want to get a good overview of a whole field you want some 101 Econ textbook such as Mankiw Principles of Economics, that has broad coverage.

If you want some deeper understanding of some topic you need some graduate level textbook (although warning you first need to have good understanding of calculus, set theory, linear algebra - depending on field). Here there are too many good textbooks to provide any answer unless you specify what exactly are you interested in.

Comment: thankyou so much for your answer, i actually intend to learn economics to better my investment strategies and actually learn and understand deeply about our world, you can say that i'm mostly curious with an intention to deeper my understanding as much as i can. i am familiar with mathematical concepts required.

Comment: @MihirMyatra if you want to learn about investing you want finance not economics. Economics can also be useful generally, but in typical economics book you won’t find any investment strategies or advice. For investing you can just pick any undergraduate finance book

Comment: yes i am aware that economics wont have strategies or advice, but learning economics can give the overall picture about a countries progress and progress directly reflects in businesses of that place, correct me if im wrong please. Also i believe, learning economics will help me see the bigger picture, which is an important factor when it comes to investing.